# debugging php on netbeans without xdebug

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans

so I heard that xdebug conflicts with other zend extensions such as APC, etc...

in light of this, are there other alternative php debuggers for netbeans available besides xdebug?

Comment: I did not have any problems with `APC + xDebug`. So, probably you should not rely on rumors, but try it yourself instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is currently "no". When Oracle decides to enable Zend Debugger support, I'll be all over it like a rash.

On the plus side, the Zend Debugger is the only extension I've had to disable to get XDebug working. APC works fine.

Comment: @alex it's more of a simile :)

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug does not conflict with APC. Only Zend's zend-extensions will cause issues, and otherwise it's most likely a bug that should be reported at http://bugs.xdebug.org.